# Usage of a C library in a C++ project (std::string char array conversion)

Tags: c++, c, c++11, library

**Abstract**

I have little C/C++ skills.  I've learned programming mainly with Java, and so I chose C++ (targeting C++11) as the language to learn better. In my current C++ project, I have to use the [discount](http://www.pell.portland.or.us/~orc/Code/discount/) C library for its Markdown functions.

To explain briefly my code: the member variable `std::string markdown_` is the Markdown I want to "compile" to HTML. To do so, I have to use the following functions from discount:

- `MMIOT *mkd_string(char *string, int size, int flags);`
- `int mkd_compile(MMIOT *document, int flags);`
- `int mkd_document(MMIOT *document, char **doc);`
- `mkd_css` and `mkd_toc` are alike `mkd_document`

**Questions**

1. As you see, I need to copy the `markdown_` string and make it a `char*`. To do so, I used a `std::vector` as suggested in [Converting an std::string into a char array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12361669/converting-an-stdstring-into-a-char-array), but I would like to know if doing it this way is appropriate in my case, or if there are other ways to achieve that.
2. `MMIOT *mkd_string(char *string, int size, int flags);` is defined in the main page to return `null` on error. Is it correct to use `nullptr` like I do in the following code to check the return value?
3. Do you have suggestions to improve this code, or does it looks good?

**Code extract**

```cpp
const std::string Markdown::error_msg_mkd_string = "libmarkdown failed to "
    "parse the following Markdown:\n";

void Markdown::compile()
{
    MMIOT* doc;
    int size;
    char *cstr_buff;
    int flags = MKD_TOC|MKD_SAFELINK|MKD_EXTRA_FOOTNOTE;

    std::vector<char> buff(markdown_.cbegin(), markdown_.cend());
    doc = mkd_string(&buff[0], buff.size(), flags);

    if(doc == nullptr)
        throw std::runtime_error(
            std::string(error_msg_mkd_string)
                .append(&buff[0], buff.size())
            );

    mkd_compile(doc, flags);

    // It is not a bad practice to reuse 'size' and 'cstr_buff' like in the
    // following code, or is it?
    size = mkd_css(doc, &cstr_buff);
    css_.assign(cstr_buff, size);

    size = mkd_document(doc, &cstr_buff);
    html_.assign(cstr_buff, size);

    size = mkd_toc(doc, &cstr_buff);
    toc_.assign(cstr_buff, size);

    mkd_cleanup(doc);
}
```

Comment: One `const` could save you a lot of head-ache. In the function `MMIOT *mkd_string(char *string, int size, int flags);` is `char *string` modified/changed in this function at all?

Comment: I just checked the discount library source code, and `mkd_string` takes indeed a `const char*` (see [mkdio.c](https://github.com/Orc/discount/blob/v2.1.7/mkdio.c)) but the function is declared without `const` in the  library documentation. @ahenderson

Comment: in that case simply use `mkd_string(markdown_.c_str(), markdown_.size(), flags);`. String `c_str()` returns the string as a `const char *`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. If `mkd_string` accepts a `const char*`, then you are better off using a `std::string` and its method `c_str()` to pass the value to the function. Otherwise your solution is correct.
2. Yes. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942103/using-nullptr-in-api-function-calls) for the why. Or build this code (tested with `g++ -std=c++0x`, gcc version 4.6):

   ```
   #include <iostream>
   int main()
   {
       if (NULL == nullptr)
           std::cout << "NULL == nullptr\n";   
   }
   ```
3. Declare the variable immediately before using it, possibly also defining it. This reduces its scope to the minimum, helps the reader/maintainer of the code understanding what the variable is for, and avoids terrible errors deriving from forgetting to initialize variables. (This should also provide you with some guideline for the question about re-using the same variable twice in the same block.)

Answer (score 1):

`std::string` has a built-in function (`c_str`) to convert the `std::string` to a `const char*`. It returns a pointer to the internal character string (terminated by a 0).

```
std::string str;
const char* cstr = str.c_str();
```

If you need a `non-const char*`, do not cast out the const. That will cause a bug. Instead, copy it to a new `non-const char*`.

```
char* cstrCopy = new char [str.length()+1];
std::strcpy (cstrCopy, str.c_str());
```